# How to restrict code in managed tool from executing?

Tags: c#

I have portions of code in my tool that I do not want to be executed when anyone other than a particular domain user runs the tool. How can I make this possible.

Comment: Is the code on the client or on the server? And is it security critical that it doesn't execute? The client can always execute any code if he really wants to.

Comment: is't a desktop tool that will also be used for admin tasks which we don't want user to be able to run

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a WinForms or Console application, you can get the identity of the current user like this:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetPrincipalPolicy(PrincipalPolicy.WindowsPrincipal);

WindowsPrincipal user = (WindowsPrincipal)System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal;
WindowsIdentity ident = user.Identity;
```

This contains a lot of information, e.g. the current user name and domain.